# Checking if a tree has alternating properties

Tags: algorithm, tree

Suppose there exists a tree where each node of the tree is either white or black, and for each internal node, its children are the opposite colour of that internal node. So if the tree were sketched, it would have the "top level" consist of (say) a black node, then the next level all white nodes, then the next level all black nodes, and so on.

Does any algorithm exist that, given a tree with root x, can check whether or not that tree meets these criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A recursive depth-first traversal should do this fairly easily. Put a method on each node which checks that all of its children are of different color, and that all of its children return true when this checker function is called on them.

Answer (score 0):

Using dept first search it's easy to know the dept of the current node being visited. 
Then based on the value of the root node you can easily check whether the current node needs to be black or white:

If the root is black (and depth of root is set to 0) then all even depth nodes need to be black and odd depth nodes white, vise-versa for a white root.

Note that you need to visit all nodes to verify the tree meets the criteria so the best possible complexity is O(n)